# Problem in setting Classpath of two different APIs in Java

Tags: java, servlets, jdbc, classpath

I'm able to set classpath of both servlet jar and mysql connector jar in environment variable but I'm not able to fetch data from database on servlet. Surprisingly I'm able to compile and get the results of both the technology individually.
The problem of fetching the data from servlet solved after I copied mysql connector jar into the jre-->lib-->ext folder. But I'm confused why the data can not be fetched only through setting up classpath in environment variables.

Comment: What servlet container do you use? If you use Tomcat or Jetty the servlet api is part of the server installation. You should place the MySQL driver's JAR file into WEB-INF/lib of your WAR file.

Comment: Yes..I use Tomcat..but what is the purpose of placing driver's JAR file into the folder specified by you? What is its significance? According to this then I should be placing everytime this JAR file into the folder for every new project I start?

Comment: You should not put things in `jre/lib/ext`: it has been removed in newer Java versions. Only the simplest ways of using Java use the `CLASSPATH` environment variable. As vanje suggested, you need to include the driver in the `WEB-INF/lib` folder as that is the proper way to define the classpath of a WAR; alternatively you can put it in tomcats lib folder to make it available to all deployed applications